# Execute specific page content as Javascript

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to look for [script][/script] tags throughout my forums and apply whatever's in between the tags to that page and hide the tags.

All I was able to do by myself was find the script tags. But how to hide them and run the script between them?

Comment: Once you strip the tags, you can do `$('#elementID').html(jQcode)`

Comment: Use [Javascript eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) method.

Comment: The title of this post is a bit weird.

Comment: Can include example `html` including `script` tags at Question ?

Comment: @Density Now it's different but previous title was not a really good description of the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `script` `type` to `text/html` , utilizing `Function`

```js
var script1 = new Function($("#one").text());
script1();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="one" type="text/html">
$("body").css("color", "blue")
</script>
<div>abc</div>
```